# Detecting dom changes with DOMSubtreeModified event

Tags: dom, events, elm, subscription

Is there any way to subscribe to `DOMSubtreeModified` event?

```
module Subscriptions.Suscription exposing (subscriptions)

import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Decode
import Models.MyModels exposing (MyModel)
import Update.Messages exposing (Msg(..))

subscriptions : MyModel -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model = 
    on "DOMSubtreeModified" (Decode.succeed (MyMSg model 0))
```

I get the following error:

```
This `on` call produces:

    Html.Attribute Msg

But the type annotation on `subscriptions` says it should be:

    Sub Msg
```

Comment: You can use [ports](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/ports.html). But judging by this and your previous question you are really pushing the limits of what Elm is suited for. Elm works best when it has full control over the DOM. Interacting with a DOM tree managed outside of Elm tends to be clunky at best and unpredictable at worst.

Comment: @glennsl, I do not want modify the DOM, only I need to know when DOM changes, to get heights of some elements and when they are bigger than X px, modify my model. Now, I am added many event listeners in many and many elements, but it is complicated because there is a huge amount of them. So, I think it its better only one listener (DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: @Amparo are you currently managing updates to the DOM in your update function? If so have you considered using https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getViewportOf?

Comment: @simplystuart, no, I are not. I only modify my model, but I need to know when DOM has changes.

Comment: Try asking this question on the elm slack channel: https://elmlang.herokuapp.com/ - I too would like to know the answer to it